# Which redirects should I use for third party share links?

Tags: wordpress, seo, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I have my WordPress blog. Every article has a Facebook, linked-in, and twitter share links. And all these links are 302 redirects. SEO recommends 301 redirects so which redirects should I use in share links?

Comment: Why are these redirects ?

Answer (score 0):

The difference in those 2 types of redirects is about giving credit to the linked page of the url for your post. They both do the same thing for the user and the crawl bot. But the 301 redirect has a second meaning for the crawler bots and it will give 90-99% of the credit and the ranking power that it would normaly be generated by the post to the redirected page. On the other hand the 302 redirects will give the redirected page 0% of ranking value.

They are both usefull but u should use the in the right way.

Lets say that u have a content and u decide to move this content to another page , site or blog. Then u are thinking what is gonna happen to the ranking that u so hardly worked for that page. The answer is simple, you will use the 301 redirect and the search engine will realise that the hole content has been moved there. That way u get to keep the rankings that u worked for even if u permanently move them.

Now if by any reason whatever might that be u wish not to pash any ranking or dont want the search engine to know that u have moved the content but u wish to redirect the users to the url page then its the right choice to use the 302 redirect.

Now i think u understand that by using the 302 redirect link. The created posts that were created from the sharing process will not give u any credit at all for they will be new posts with a 302 redirect on them.

By using the 301 redirect u will receive all the credit for the created posts and that is exactly the reason they are recommended.

You can look for more information [here.](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection)

I hope i could be of some help, feel free to ask more if u need more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have quit understand what you said so I guess the 302 redirects that has been used on my share links should be right. Because I think there is no need to know search engine bot to third party websites like Facebook, twitter. Correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: Wrong cause we are talking about the links that will be generated from the  new created posts via sharing process. And you want those to be 301 redirects .

Comment: <a class="share-facebook sd-button share-icon" title="Share on Facebook" href="https://www.example.com/blog/my-test/?share=facebook&nb=1" data-shared="sharing-facebook-304" rel="nofollow">. above is my link of Facebook share. I had added my website on "onpage.org" for seo. And it detects all these share links and recommends to use 301 redirects. So my question is there is already rel="nofollow" in links then why it detects? And how to use 301 redirects here?